# Flutter webview with innerHTML callback issue

Tags: flutter, webview-flutter

I am calling a webview, lets call it main `index.html` that has a JS file with `displayAlert()` method.
It has another `index.html` as its `innerHTML`(this is inside a test folder).
Whenever i call `await webViewController.runJavascript("displayAlert()");`, it gives `Uncaught ReferenceError : displayAlert is not defined, source:file"///PATH_TO_ANDROID_STORAGE/test/index.html`
Somehow the callback is being forwarded to `innerHTML` instead of main `index.html` processing it.
This happens only on android and not on iOS.
I am using "https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading correctly, you are importing index.html from assets that has a `<Script>` tag with a link to another asset file.

As of December 2022 **This does not work in Flutter WebView.**

You need to embed your JS file code into the actual index.html or link to a public resource on the web, i.e.
`<script src="https://example.tld/my.js"></script>`

Comment: do you have any sources i can refer?